# We have too many [ceiling-fans] in our Stack

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The [ceiling-fans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling-fans) tag should become a synonym for [ceiling-fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling-fan).  (Besides, there are some klutzes who put [ceiling](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling) and [fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan) on their ceiling fan question -- that should be rectified sometime as well...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it should!

It was an obvious synonym, so I went ahead and merged them. You should only see [ceiling-fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling-fan) from now on.

As I write this, we have <s>[36 questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling+fans) tagged with both [ceiling](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling) and [fans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fans)... not a huge job to edit out those tags and replace with [ceiling-fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling-fan)</s> no questions left with the [ceiling](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceiling) and [fans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fans) tags.

If we get some ceiling fan questions in the future with those tags, and anyone wants to help with the cleanup, remember to do a few at a time so that the front page doesn't get flooded with edits, and fix all the problems with the post (typos, formatting, etc.)

---

<sub>For what it's worth, I'm not a huge fan of the [fans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fans) tag either; I'd be in favor of more specific tags for the type of fan: [exhaust-fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exhaust-fan), [duct-fan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duct-fan), and so on. But that's a <s>story</s> meta question for another day...</sub>